How to identify if user is in a call using ringcentral's api
What I want to accomplish is to check if an agent is in the middle of a call for business logic.
I think the right endpoint to use is https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Control/readCallSessionStatus but after reading the docs I'm not sure from where to get telephonySessionId and in this case if a telephonySessionId exists doesn't that mean the user is in the middle of any type of call?

Use ringcentral List User Active Calls api to get calls that are calls that are in progress
you will get telephonySessionId from this api too
https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Log/listExtensionActiveCalls
